# Script doesn't work when is called from code, but it works ok when it's typed in console

Tags: jquery, css, html

I'm using [flexslider](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/) widget to show a photo gallery. It uses simple markup because when the document loads, the markup it's adapted to the viewport and it's styled using a script when document is ready. Everything works ok when the page is loaded. But I need to add a "selector", I mean, when someone clicks a link, a new gallery should be loaded in the flexslider widget. So, using jquery I'm selecting the corresponding gallery div and writing new contents with $.("#galleryID").empty().append(new-markup);

So, the DOM structure changes, but the flexslider doesn't show because it needs to be "completed" by running the js code that adapts to the viewport and styles it. Then, I tried "re-run" the script needed after the div is modified, but the div remains blank. If I run the same script from the console window, the div shows correctly.

Now I'm using the $.getScript() jquery method, to force loading again the adapting and styling script, but sometimes work, and sometimes doesn't. And in Firefox works fine: everytime you click the selector, loads the gallery ok and run the scripts, but Chrome doesn't, sometimes it does, sometimes the div remains white (with the correct markup but without the modifications needed).

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    $('a.pgal').click(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('hashtag');
    /*get the gallery elements (imgs, titles, etc)*/
    $.get("listgal.php", {hashtag:id}, function(objetogal){
    var x=0;
    /*create the flexslider markup*/
    var codigo='<div id="slider" class="flexslider"><ul class="slides">';
    var codigocarousel='<div id="carousel" class="flexslider"><ul class="slides">';
    var elementos=objetogal.length;
    for(x=0;x<elementos;x++)
    {
      codigo=codigo+ '<li><img src="fotos/'+ objetogal[x].img +'" /><p class="flex-caption">'+objetogal[x].pie+'</p></li>'
      codigocarousel=codigocarousel+'<li><img src="fotos/'+ objetogal[x].img +'" />';
    }
    codigo=codigo+'</ul></div>';
    codigocarousel=codigo+codigocarousel+'</ul></div>';

    /*Change the gallery div with this new markup*/
    $("#galeriaID").empty().append(codigocarousel);
    }, "json");
    $.getScript("js/renueva.js", function(){
    });
    return false;
    });
    </script>
```

renueva.js *This is the code needed to style and adapt to the viewport the gallery using the markup as source. Its the code I tried to include in the same script after the div refresh, but it didn't do anything. But running in the console worked fine. I'm trying now with $.getScript but sometimes the markup it's processed, sometimes don't, using Chrome. Using Firefox works flawlessly*

```
$('#carousel').flexslider({
animation: "slide",
controlNav: false,
animationLoop: false,
slideshow: false,
itemWidth: 90,
itemMargin: 5,
asNavFor: '#slider'
});
$('#slider').flexslider({
animation: "slide",
controlNav: false,
animationLoop: false,
slideshow: false,
sync: "#carousel",
start: function(slider){
}
});
```

The HTML markup

```
        <div class="col-xs-12 w12 col-md-9" id="galeriabr">
          <div id="slider" class="flexslider">
            <ul class="slides">
              <li>
                <img src="fotos/armas.jpg" />
                <p class="flex-caption">Se presentan 98 delitos al día en Michoacán</p>
              </li>
              <li>
                <img src="fotos/sep.jpg" />
                <p class="flex-caption">Se tomarán medidas para garantizar evaluación a maestros: SEP</p>
              </li>
              <li>
                <img src="fotos/eleccion.jpg" />
                <p class="flex-caption">Scioli gana elección de Argentina pero puede haber segunda vuelta</p>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div id="carousel" class="flexslider">
            <ul class="slides">
              <li>
                <img src="fotos/armas.jpg" />
              </li>
              <li>
                <img src="fotos/sep.jpg" />
              </li>
              <li>
                <img src="fotos/eleccion.jpg" />
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>              
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a mistake in the loop where the markup is formed, the < /li> tag was abscent. It works better now but sometimes it shows the blank div again. I changed the $.getScript() line to:

```
    $.when(
    $.getScript( "js/renueva.js" ),
    $.Deferred(function( deferred ){
    $( deferred.resolve );
     })
    ).done(function(){
      recarga();
     });
```

"recarga()" it's a function inside "renueva.js" I will continue seeking another answer to this because it's not perfect yet. I need to show the gallery everytime it's clicked it's selector, not 9 of every 10 clicks.